# How to convert nullable MutableMap to not nullable in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

How to turn nullable map into not nulllable keeping all keys, mapping all null values to a specific one?

`val map = Map<String, Any?>` to `val map = Map<String, Any>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering you want to map null values to a specific one, I would suggest you do something like this instead:

```
 val nonNullMap = map.mapValues { it.value ?: “undefined” }
```

Where “undefined” is your default value if a null is encountered in your map. If you use the double-bang operator (!!), you will get a KotlinNullPointerException if the value happens to be a null.

Comment: `it.value`, not `it.values` I think.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thanks, I’ve updated., silly auto correct from my iPad.